# How is argument unpacking working in this function?

Tags: python

I'm still a beginner in learning python but I came across this function :

```
def  show_skills (name , *skills ,**skillswithprogress) :
   
   print (f'hello {name} \n skills without progress is :')
   for skill in skills :
      print (f'-{skills}')
   print ('skills with progress is :')
   for skill_key , skills_value in skillswithprogress.items():
      print(f'-{skill_key} =>{skills_value}')


show_skills('H', python = '95%',css = '95%')
```

and the output for it  is as follows:

```
hello H 
 skills without progress is :
skills with progress is : 
-python =>95%
-css =>95%
```

Can anyone explain explain why did [python = '95%',css = '95%'] get treated like that, not as *skills ?

Comment: `**skillswithprogress` collects keyword parameters.  `*skills` collects non-keyword (positional) parameters. (thanks chepner)

Comment: in you case both are keyword arguments so both will be considered as `skillswithprogress`.

Comment: @CryptoFool The term you are looking for is *keyword arguments*, not "named parameters". (Parameters and arguments are quite distinct concepts.)

Comment: Arguments are the *value* you provide to a function *call*. Parameters are the names you provide in a function *definition*.

Answer (score 0):

It is the concept of `*args` and `**kwargs`

`*args` is the list or tuple

`**kwargs` is the dictionary

you put the parameter for the function as like
`show_skills('H', python = '95%',css = '95%')`

would be `python='95%', css='95%' => {python:'95%', css:'95%'}`

Comment: `*args` defines a tuple, period.